# CSS Magnifying Glass (Increase zoom level)

Tags: javascript, html, css

First: I am familiarize very little with Javascript but mostly I do CSS and HTML.

I am creating a website and I have a very big image so I downloaded a code to implement the magnifying glass effect on a picture. However the image has a lot of details that requires to zoom more to appreciate. Is there any way I can modify this code to create a deeper level of zoom of the image?

This is the code I used:

https://codepen.io/akhbar/pen/Biupr

I believe this is the most relevant part of the code that creates the magnifying glass effect:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var native_width = 0;
    var native_height = 0;
  $(".large").css("background","url('" + $(".small").attr("src") + "') no-repeat");

    //Now the mousemove function
    $(".magnify").mousemove(function(e){
        //When the user hovers on the image, the script will first calculate
        //the native dimensions if they don't exist. Only after the native dimensions
        //are available, the script will show the zoomed version.
        if(!native_width && !native_height)
        {
            //This will create a new image object with the same image as that in .small
            //We cannot directly get the dimensions from .small because of the 
            //width specified to 200px in the html. To get the actual dimensions we have
            //created this image object.
            var image_object = new Image();
            image_object.src = $(".small").attr("src");

            //This code is wrapped in the .load function which is important.
            //width and height of the object would return 0 if accessed before 
            //the image gets loaded.
            native_width = image_object.width;
            native_height = image_object.height;
        }
        else
        {
            //x/y coordinates of the mouse
            //This is the position of .magnify with respect to the document.
            var magnify_offset = $(this).offset();
            //We will deduct the positions of .magnify from the mouse positions with
            //respect to the document to get the mouse positions with respect to the 
            //container(.magnify)
            var mx = e.pageX - magnify_offset.left;
            var my = e.pageY - magnify_offset.top;

            //Finally the code to fade out the glass if the mouse is outside the container
            if(mx < $(this).width() && my < $(this).height() && mx > 0 && my > 0)
            {
                $(".large").fadeIn(100);
            }
            else
            {
                $(".large").fadeOut(100);
            }
            if($(".large").is(":visible"))
            {
                //The background position of .large will be changed according to the position
                //of the mouse over the .small image. So we will get the ratio of the pixel
                //under the mouse pointer with respect to the image and use that to position the 
                //large image inside the magnifying glass
                var rx = Math.round(mx/$(".small").width()*native_width - $(".large").width()/2)*-1;
                var ry = Math.round(my/$(".small").height()*native_height - $(".large").height()/2)*-1;
                var bgp = rx + "px " + ry + "px";

                //Time to move the magnifying glass with the mouse
                var px = mx - $(".large").width()/2;
                var py = my - $(".large").height()/2;
                //Now the glass moves with the mouse
                //The logic is to deduct half of the glass's width and height from the 
                //mouse coordinates to place it with its center at the mouse coordinates

                //If you hover on the image now, you should see the magnifying glass in action
                $(".large").css({left: px, top: py, backgroundPosition: bgp});
            }
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: Please add the relevant part of your code to your question.

Comment: It looks like you simply need to provide a larger version of the magnified image (a png would probably be better than a jpg).

Comment: @AndrewMorton a jpg is definitely the better option because it will be compressed (it's a lossy format), while png is uncompressed and does no compression. There is no difference in resolution between the two though. A higher res JPG can actually be a smaller file than a lower res png. So he should continue using a JPG for the best page load times.

Comment: @XanderLuciano PNGs can definitely be compressed - and with lossless compression. For viewing details, a lossless compression is preferable to a lossy compression. [You can search for "png compressor".]

Comment: PNG's can be compressed into less colors and compressed that way, but PNG is still a lossless format. JPG will have some artifacts, but I think JPG is still the better option since you could push a higher resolution, but I guess it might depend on what type of photos he has. If image has a lot of color detail, JPG compression might not be **that** effective.

Comment: Thank you for your opinions, indeed, changing the PNG to JPG changed the whole thing. It was really helpful, I appreciate everyone's comment :)